# sorting nested {{#each}} in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, each, meteor-blaze, spacebars

In meteors guide i found the code below and I was wondering if todo.tags could be sorted somehow, maybe by a helpers method?

```
{{#each todo in todos}}
  {{#each tag in todo.tags}}
    <!-- in here, both todo and tag are in scope -->
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Can you post the javascript helpers code too?

Comment: There is no helpers code. I found this code in the Meteor guide here: http://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html
Normally, the todo.tags would appear in a natural order (in the order the were put into the collection/document) but I would like to sort them.

Comment: change todo.tags to this.tags

Comment: In which order do you want to sort them?

Comment: Ascending order by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a separate template helper which sorts all elements in your `tags` array. To sort the elements in an ascending order, you could use **[`_.sortBy(list, iteratee, [context])`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)**, for example:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.todos.helpers({
    todos: function() {
      return Todos.find();
    },
    sortedTags: function(todo) {
      return _.sortBy(todo.tags, function(tag) {
        return tag;
      });
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (Todos.find().count() === 0) {
      Todos.insert({
        name: "homework",
        tags: ["school", "college", "university"]
      });
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
<template name="todos">
  {{#each todo in todos}}
    {{todo.name}}
    <ul>
      {{#each tag in sortedTags todo}}
        <li>{{tag}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

---

This can also be implemented with your sample data structure, provided in the comments:

```
{
   "gtext":"Money",
   "owner":"qDqGDaXjaHXNhX95u",
   "username":"prsz",
   "order":0,
   "tasks":[
      {
         "taskName":"Test subtask1",
         "taskOrder":3
      },
      {
         "taskName":"Test subtask2",
         "taskOrder":1
      }
   ]
}
```

---

```
<template name="goals">
  {{#each goal in goals}}
    {{goal.gtext}}
    <ul>
      {{#each task in sortedTasks goal}}
        <li>{{task.taskName}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.goals.helpers({
    goals: function() {
      return Goals.find();
    },
    sortedTasks: function(goal) {
      return _.sortBy(goal.tasks, function(task) {
        return task.taskOrder;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Here's a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/D2ePZCHCQpjzoiMQg/Each-In-Sort-Goals).

Comment: Thank you @Matthias Eckhart, now I understand!
 Can I use this with a sample dataset like this?
{ "_id" : "ZDCwfD4pWfD7sZ9DB", "gtext" : "Money", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-12-26T13:15:59.563Z"), "owner" : "qDqGDaXjaHXNhX95u", "username" : "prsz", "order" : 0, "tasks" : [ { "taskName" : "Test subtask1", "taskOrder" : 3 }, { "taskName" : "Test subtask2", "taskOrder" : 1 } ] }


Template.body.helpers({         
goals: function() {
      return Goals.find({},{sort: {'order': 1}});     
        } 
  });

Comment: `Template.goal.helpers({
   sortedTasks: function(tasks) {
      return _.sortBy(tasks.taskOrder, function(task) {
        return task;
      });
    } 
});

      {{#each goals}}
        {{> goal}}
      {{/each}}`

Like the subtasks are an array of objects

Comment: Hey @Matthias Thank you for your contribution to my todolist! I wasn't able to solve this ordering issue for weeks. I'll show you the end result

Comment: @Peter You are welcome! I am excited to see the end result, shoot me the link to your app on Twitter.